# Dart: Lambda confusion

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm beginning with Dart (java developer here)

I am trying to understand the following construct:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App j'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: quotes.map((quote) =>  {
          String text = prepareString(quote);
          return Text(text);
        }).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Click!'),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
```

problem is the lambda expression with quote. Why on earth I can't use such construct to simply map quote object -> Text widget? Because this doesn't return List of Widget objects as I would expect but List<Set> which doesn't make sense....

Yes I can do the following:

```
body: Column(
        children: quotes.map((quote) => Text(prepareString(quote)).toList(),
      ),
```

that works. But this should be equal to previous block syntax, shouldn't it?

Can anybody point me to explanation of this? Dart is very confusing here...

Thanks.

Comment: Just remove =>, {} Creates a set. Lambdas in dart go like () { ... }, When you put =>,  it implies you are returning something inline

Comment: You were right, removing lambda operator and just sticking with block syntax makes it work with multiple rows....Thanks a lot.

Comment: `=>` is not a "lambda operator".  A [lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) is just an anonymous function. `() => x` is just syntactic sugar for `() { return x; }`. Both are anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

In flutter you can use `lambda` function in two different forms.

```
1. list.map((x)=>Text("Hello"));
```

This syntax uses the arrow notation `=>` to build a `lambda` function that accepts one input `x` and returns a `Text` widget. Since this lambda function is straightforward and has only one expression, this is a shorter, more direct method to define it.

```
2. list.map((x){
   // declartion or assignment here ;
   return Text("Hello"):}
```

This syntax employs curly brackets `{}` to build a lambda function that accepts one parameter, `x` declares or assigns variables inside the function body, and returns a `Text` widget . When the lambda function is more complicated and calls for several statements, or when you wish to declare or assign variables inside the function body, this syntax is generally used.

---

In your code you are using `=>` with `{}`, which is not valid. Try one of the above code.

Changes to be made in your code is:

```
 children: quotes.map((quote) {                 // remove the => operator
          String text = prepareString(quote);
          return Text(text);
        }).toList(),
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I did in the end. Thanks for explanation.